# jQuery toggle slide element but not completely hide element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

The following example is probably the easiest way to try and explain the effect I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/qSscJ/2/

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#handle').click(function() {
        $('#box').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' });
    });
});
```

Click on the blue handle to make the entire red box collapse.  How do I keep the blue handle visible after the box is collapsed (while keeping the handle anchored to the edge of the box)?  I'm open to other jQuery UI APIs to achieve this effect.

Comment: put the handle out side of box

Comment: How do you keep it anchored to that left edge of the box though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do just animate the width directly so the element doesn't get marked as hidden at the end of the animation:

```
$(function() {
    $('#handle').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({width: "0px"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

But, it would be much better to change the design so that the blue tab was not contained within the box you're closing like here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gKQrv/.

```
$(function() {
    $('#handle').click(function() {
        var box = $('#box');
        var targetWidth = box.width() > 0 ? 0 : 150;
        box.animate({width: targetWidth + "px"}, 1000);
    });
});
```